# Accepting list as input to gcd (x,y)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a function that accepts list as an argument to my `gcd` function. Would something like this work?

```
def find_my_gcd(a_list):
    def gcd (x,y):
        while y!=0:
             x,y=y,x%y
        return x
```

Now,how do I make my `gcd` function step through a list,i.e `a_list=[12,24,18,6]`, iterate through `gcd(12,24)`, `gcd(12,18)`,`gcd(12,6)` and returns a single value.

Answer (score 0):

you have to keep the current value in a variable, and use that with the next value in the list, something like this

```
def find_my_gcd(a_list):
    def gcd (x,y):
        while y!=0:
            x,y=y,x%y
        return x
    acum = a_list[0]
    for e in a_list[1:]:
        acum = gcd(acum,e)
    return acum
```

you can also use [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) to keep the acumulated for you

```
def find_my_gcd(a_list):
    def gcd (x,y):
        while y!=0:
            x,y=y,x%y
        return x
    return reduce(gcd,a_list)
```

also you can find gcd in the [math.gcd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd) library in python 3.5+ and in previous versions is in [fractions.gcd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.gcd) library so the your function can be reduced to

```
from functools import reduce
from math import gcd # from fractions import gcd in 3.4 or previous

def find_my_gcd(a_list):
    return reduce(gcd,a_list)
```